# install packages from elm.json

Tags: dependencies, elm

[image: pe]

The system has elm installed, and trying to install packages from elm.json.

What is the procedure to install packages from the elm.json directly?

currently, I have to install independently one by one.

**elm install elm/http**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `elm install` command without any input will give the following hint

> Hint: In JavaScript folks run `npm install` to start projects. "Gotta download
>   everything!" But why download packages again and again? Instead, Elm caches
>   packages in /Users/kaskelotti/.elm so each one is downloaded and built
>   ONCE on your machine. Elm projects check that cache before trying the internet.
>   This reduces build times, reduces server costs, and makes it easier to work
>   offline. As a result elm install is only for adding dependencies to elm.json,
>   whereas elm make is in charge of gathering dependencies and building everything.
>   So maybe try elm make instead?

As the tip says, `elm make` is probably what you need.

If your elm cache is missing some dependencies, they are downloaded as needed.

Comment: Urrgh, I love Elm as a language and concept (although I wish it had adopted more from Haskell to avoid boilerplate), but this kind of opinionated "I know better than everyone else" is exactly the kind of thing you don't want to see in a compiler error or command line output (or in library documentation where you also see it quite a bit, sadly). Is there anything wrong with just explaining politely what to do without the "I know best" attitude?

Comment: Maybe it has some strong opinions that could arguably be toned down a bit. But still probably most of Elm user base come from JavaScript background and are used to tools such as npm and yarn. I think it's good to explain how and why things are done differently with Elm.

Comment: Totally agree it should be explained. It's just the tone I dislike. In this case I take exception to `Gotta download everything!" But why download packages again and again?` - but there are worse examples I've seen in library documentation. Sorry, I know this is off topic, but I just think things like this should inform your users without patronising them or sounding opinionated.